# Unity 5 - Collider vs timer in thread

Tags: multithreading, performance, unity-game-engine, collider

I had a question related to performances.

Here's the context :

Imagine a TempleRun-like game in which the player only moves in 1 direction and is allowed to switch between 3 lanes (all of them going in the same direction).

Unlike temple run, there are no turns.

I wish to make the level generate dynamically and therefore we placed colliders on the ground. When triggered, the level loads the next (random) part of the path and unloads the old one.

Since the player is moving at a constant speed in 1 direction, I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to use a timer to load and unload game parts?

Also, I was wondering how colliders were handled by Unity? Do they work with a thread constantly watching for a collision to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use time in case I want to change the speed of the player through a boost or some other reason.

Here's some information on colliders:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/collision-detection-at-high-speed.3353/

From what I read, it feels like there is a separate thread that has a fixed time step and fires events to alert when a collision happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links ;) But what if there is not boost? A timer would be less expensive than the collision detection process, wouldn't it?

Comment: If I were to code this, I would use a grid system. The player's z position is always 0 and they control the x position. The level would move a set z value per second, using lerp to create a nice smooth movement. Every time a piece of the level reaches a certain z value, remove it and place another at the front. So technically I would use a timer, but I would calculate it from a speed value and use the results in a lerp function.